# Pkg.installed("anInvalidPackage") , should return nothing or throw an error?

Tags: julia

refer to this paragraph:

> installed(pkg) → Void | VersionNumber
>
> ```
> If pkg is installed, return the installed version number, otherwise return nothing.
> ```

from  [JuliaDoc](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/pkg/#package-manager-functions)

`Pkg.installed("anInvalidPackage")` function should return `nothing` but it throws an error:

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.5.0"
julia> Pkg.installed("anInvalidPackage")
ERROR: anInvalidPackage is not a package (not registered or installed)
 in installed(::String) at .\pkg\entry.jl:123
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#installed,Tuple{String}})
() at .\pkg\dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#installed,Tuple{String}
}, ::String) at .\file.jl:48
 in #cd#1 at .\pkg\dir.jl:31
 in installed(::String) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:129
```

**EDIT** : [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19436)

Comment: Strange how it removed "an" from the string...

Comment: @daycaster typo

Comment: "Well, Watson, that's eliminated that line of enquiry!" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we tale a look at the source code for the Pkg module in base it should give use some clues:

```
function installed(pkg::AbstractString)
    avail = Read.available(pkg)
    if Read.isinstalled(pkg)
        res = typemin(VersionNumber)
        ### some libgit2 stuff ###
    end
    isempty(avail) && throw(PkgError("$pkg is not a package (not registered or installed)"))
    return nothing # registered but not installed
end
```

From the last two lines we can see that Julia is going to throw an error if the package is **not registered** or installed. However if the package **is registered** but not installed then no error will be thrown and `nothing` is returned.

So

```
var = Pkg.installed("AMD") # returns nothing for me as I don't have AMD installed
                           # but it is a registered package
```

But:

```
 altvar = Pkg.installed("this_is_not_the_name_of_any_package")
 # will throw an error
```

I agree the docs should probably make this more clear...